# Angular $http service's `then` method takes 2 args (success & error callbacks). Since there's an error callback, what is the point of using `catch`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The Angular $http service has a `then` method that takes 2 arguments as callbacks (one for success & one for error). Since there's an error callback already, what is the point of using `catch` method?  And why use it?

Here's a `then`-`catch` implementation:

```
$http.get("url").then(
  function(results) {
    //do something w/results.data
  }).catch(function(e){
    // handle errors in processing or in error.
  });
```

---

Here's a `then` implementation with 2 arguments:

```
$http.get("url").then(
  //success function
  function(results) {
    //do something w/results.data
  },
  //error function
  function(err) {
    //handle error
  }
);
```

---

**EDIT**: The question here is different than what [New Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968155/new-dev) is proposing.  The question here is specifically about **`then`'s fail callback vs `catch`**, while the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596384/in-angular-whats-the-conceptual-difference-between-the-error-and-catch-functio/) is about **`error` vs `catch`**.  Albeit, there was one response in the other topic that alluded to `then`'s fail callback. I vote to keep this open to garner better responses and to help users specifically looking for "`then`'s fail callback vs `catch`" questions.

Comment: This answer may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19599501/1862339

Comment: Actually, $http.get returns a promise.  It's the promise which has the then/catch methods.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate - as suggested in comments and answers - of [In Angular, what's the conceptual difference between the error and catch functions for promises?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596384/in-angular-whats-the-conceptual-difference-between-the-error-and-catch-functio)

Comment: @NewDev, my question is about `then`'s fail callback vs catch.  The question in your link is about `error` vs `catch`.  They're different.

Comment: @ayjay, I don't get what the difference is. Both questions are about `then(success, error)` vs. `then(success).catch(error)`

Comment: @ayjay, did any of the answers below address you question?

Comment: @NewDev, I think you might be right.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between

```
promise.then(onSuccess, onError)
```

and

```
promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError)
```

is that in the first case, `onError` handles exceptions/rejections of `promise`, whereas in the second case - `onError` handles exceptions/rejections of both the original `promise` and those generated by `onSuccess`.

This may not seem like much, but the distinction becomes critical when you chain promises.

Promises can be thought of as an **async** equivalent of the `try`/`catch` blocks - which is what their true strength is.

Consider the following synchronous call sequence:

```
var result;
try {
  var d1 = doSomething1();
  var d2 = doSomething2(d1);
  var d3 = doSomething3(d2);

  result = d3;
}
catch(e){
  // land here if any of the above throws an exception
  result = "not set";
}
```

With promises and the async versions of `doSomethingN` the following would be equivalent:

```
var result;
doSomething1()
 .then(doSomething2)
 .then(doSomething3)

 .then(function(d3){
    result = d3;
 })
 .catch(function(){
    // land here if anything above throws an exception or returns a rejection
    result = "not set";
 });
```

So, an exception or a rejection of a promise in any `doSomethingN` would get to a `catch` handler.

And this is where the error handler of `.then` becomes counter-intuitive. So, if you had something like this:

```
var result;
doSomething1()
 .then(doSomething2)
 .then(doSomething3, errorHandler3)

 .then(function(d3){ 
    result = d3; 
 })
 .catch(function() { 
    result = "not set"; 
 });
```

then `errorHandler3` is called to handle an error of `doSomething2` or, of  `doSomething1` (if there is no `errorHandler2`). But not of `doSomething3`. And, in fact, it is expected to "*handle*" the error - as in, the expectation is that it ought to return a valid `d3`-like result instead of what `doSomething3` would have returned. Either that, or "re-throw" (with `return $q.reject()`).

And the sync equivalent would be the following mess (which I hope I got it right):

```
var d2, d3;
try {
  var d1 = doSomething1();
  d2 = doSomething2(d1);
}
catch(e){
  d3 = errorHandler3(e);
}

try {
  if (!d3) d3 = doSomething3(d2);
}
catch (e){
  d3 = "not set";
}
result = d3;
```

Answer (score 1):

`then` is there for interoperability, because it is expected by the JS Promise API ([source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-lib-compatibility)):

> The JavaScript promises API will treat anything with a `then` method as
>   promise-like (or *thenable* in promise-speak * *sigh* *), so if you use a
>   library that returns a Q promise, that's fine, it'll play nice with
>   the new JavaScript promises.

`catch` on the other hand is preferable because it is more expressive. See: [In Angular, what's the conceptual difference between the error and catch functions for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19599501/1862339)

In the case of Angular's $http, one could also argue to use `success` and `error` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I think in the problem I'm trying to solve, I'm finding that I am needing to use `then`'s fail callback.  The `catch` doesn't seem to capture the corner case.

Answer (score 0):

by catch, i'm assuming you mean a try/catch block. You'd use a try catch block to try and capture an exception that happens during runtime execution  and handle it in a meaningful way.

$http is not encapsulating your code in this try/catch fashion. It attempts to make a request, and is calling the success function if it receives a status code that indicates that request was successful, the error function is called to indicate an unsuccessful request. You'll have to inspect the provided arguments to determine the reason.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

When the error function is called, it's still up to you to determine how to handle that error.

---

The $q also has a .catch and .finally option. The .catch(onRejected) is an alias for promise.then(null, errorCallback)- which would still put the error handling in your hands.

> Blockquote promise.catch(onRejected) 
>   Alias: promise.fail (for non-ES5
>   browsers) A sugar method, equivalent to promise.then(undefined,
>   onRejected).

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback

Comment: Ah, you're referring to the actual promise API callback options. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback      it appears the catch is just an alias for promise.then(null,errorcallback)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** this depends on the implimentation of the promise library used.

The main benefit of using `.catch()` is that it allows you to catch any un-handled error anywhere in the promise chain.

```
$http({ ... })
    .then( thing1 )
    .then( thing2 )
    .then( thing3 )
    .then( thing4 )
    .then( thing5 )
    .catch( function( err ){
        console.log( 'An error occurred while processing the response' )
    })
```

Comment: I'm asking about `then`'s 2nd argument vs `catch`.  You only explained `catch`.  How is this different than `then`'s fail callback?

Comment: @ayjay Functionally it seems they are the same. Visually, `catch` is a "if an error happens anywhere in this chain, do something", whereas `then arg 2` is "when something errors in the previous promise".